# How do I change the color of the icon when I hover my mouse on it?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[I got the icon like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNJHa.png)

When the user hover over the icon, how can I change the blue color to a different one using HTML or CSS?

Updated: Here's the css code:

```
.timeline-centered .timeline-entry .timeline-entry-inner .timeline-icon {
    background: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    color: #737881;
    display: block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px #f5f5f6;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px #f5f5f6;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px #f5f5f6;
    line-height: 40px;
    font-size: 15px;
    float: left;
}

.timeline-centered .timeline-entry .timeline-entry-inner .timeline-icon.bg-primary {
    background-color: #309BDF;
    color: #fff;
}

.timeline-centered .timeline-entry .timeline-entry-inner .timeline-icon.bg-primary:hover {
    background-color: #a3bbe0;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: show us what you have tried?

Comment: post  your code add snippet.

Comment: Put the code here! Because there are many ways

Answer (score -2):

Html

```
<div class="bg">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.bg{
width:20px;
height:20px;
background-color:green;
}

.bg:hover{
  background-color:red;
 }
```

Comment: What's wrong in this?. If you don't know the answer let other's answer. Don't give down vote...

Answer (score -2):

Use `filter` property, most likely adjust `hue-rotate` to get the intended color:

```
img:hover {
    -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(90deg); /* Safari 6.0 - 9.0 */
    filter: hue-rotate(45deg);
}
```

Source: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_filter_huerotate